# Newly requested permissions in app settings are not reflected in the app itself

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions

Recently i realized that i need more than basic information for my facebook application.
I need the user's birthday as well.

In my App permissions configuration i added "user_birthday" and by checking the example given by facebook the permission was added successfully.
(goes without saying that i clicked "Save changes")

when im trying to log in to my application the "user_birthday" does not appear.
(after waiting several minutes and another 24H)

any ideas what else do i need to configure in facebook?

Comment: Where are you expecting the users birthday to "appear"?  You have to request it. Checkout `/me`. The birthday parameter should appear there.

Comment: i am expecting it to appear in the log in api of facebook when i first accept the application.
im sorry i dont understand the /me part.

Comment: How are you requesting the users information?

Comment: in http://developers.facebook.com/ i go to my app.

there to permmisions

there i added "user_birthday" in User & Friend Permissions.

Comment: Yes, you have said that.  But you actually have to request information.  Simply asking for the permissions doesn't get you any info - it just allows you to request it. I think you need to go over the documentation again.

Comment: hag sameach!
im using ruby on rails, i did not changed anything yet.
first of all i want to see if the auth dialog is updated.

Comment: can you please send me an email so can explain my problam more fluently?

Comment: I'm sorry - but that is not the way I operate on [so]. What you are talking about is very basic Facebook operations. Perhaps if you go over the basics again things will fall into place.

Answer (score 3):

> when im trying to log in to my application the "user_birthday" does not appear.

Are you triggering the login from within your app’s code yourself?

> In my App permissions configuration i added "user_birthday"

**These settings are for [Authenticated Referrals](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals) only.** Unless your login is triggered by those, these settings will have no effect.

If you are triggering login yourself, you have to request the permission via the `scope` parameter.

Comment: thank you

i dont really know where the scope is? is it something i need to trigger int the fb.login?

im not developing a canvas app, its a web app.

Comment: If you don’t know what the scope parameter is, then please read the authentication docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: I read it all.
as i writen before i did it all.

is it possible to achive that without a cookie?

Comment: Cookies are generally required for most things connected to Facebook login to work seamlessly. But what do cookies have to do with your actual question now?

Comment: probably nothing.
i think there is a piece of information that im missing.
my goal is now to be able to see the fact that i am requesting user birthday on the auth dialog.
afterwards, i probably need only to add:
`response.user_birthday`

Comment: Well, then put that permission into the scope parameter of your login/Auth dialog call.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're missing out the fact that the
[permission scope](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)
is by default not set on facebook's development plattform. It's usually done though the login link.

If you want every user to be prompted for certain permissions you need to enable "authenticated referrals" as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals).

All SDK's allow a scope parameter for the login link. You can add the scope manually to every link using a scope parameter, like so:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
   &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
   &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
   &code=CODE_GENERATED_BY_FACEBOOK
   &scope=user_about_me,user_birthday
```

Comment: In the OP's defence, there is a feature on Facebook's side ('Authenticated Referrals') which automatically prompts users to allow permissions to your app from App Center or links to your app on facebook.com, which takes the permission set to be prompted from the app settings, but as the other answer clarified, the OP isn't using that flow

Comment: Cool, do you know how to do that? I don't know about that flow? Would be interesting, maybe you edit my post or writ an answer, that would help me and probably some others.

Comment: It's documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals